# Keyboard shortcut to toggle auto-hide unity launcher

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, python

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut to toggle the auto-hide option for the unit launcher. Based on the answer on [How to programmatically change the launcher's hide behaviour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231893/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-sidebar-auto-hide-behaviour/231921#231921) I tried to make a python script to do the job. Then I should just figure out how to run that with a keyboard shortcut.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/python
AUTOHIDE=$(dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode)
if (AUTOHIDE==1):
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 0
else:
    dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 1
```

But running the script from a terminal (doing 'python scriptname.py' ) doesn't work. I get a "invalid syntax" error at $ sign.

You have to know that I have almost no knowledge of python (or writing scripts in general). (I've just spent a few hours searching the web for help and examples).

So the actual questions:

- What did I do wrong?
- Did I chose a way to complicated approach for this and how can I do it more easily in that case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to do it Pythonic way.

```
#!/bin/python
import subprocess
AUTOHIDE = subprocess.check_output (["/usr/bin/dconf", "read", "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode"])
if (AUTOHIDE==1):
   subprocess.call (["/usr/bin/dconf", "write", "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode", "0"])
else:
   subprocess.call (["/usr/bin/dconf", "write", "/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode", "1"])
```

you have to execute the programs by creating a subprocess.

And this is the bash script version

```
#!/bin/bash
AUTOHIDE=$(dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode)
if [[ $AUTOHIDE -eq 1 ]]
then
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 0
else
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 1
fi
```

The shortcut can be assigned like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/137119/138784).

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04, I had to change the Python code to  `if (int(AUTOHIDE)==1):`, since AUTOHIDE was a string (either `'1\n'` or `'0\n'`).

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it simply is to create a custom shortcut.

Access System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom shortcuts
Then click '+' to add a new shortcut, and in the command box paste:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 0
```

This will create a shortcut for showing the launcher. Now to hide the launcher, you should create another shortcut adding the command:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/launcher-hide-mode 1
```

Of course, now you'll have one command for each function, but I put them side by side and find it very intuitive.

Comment: I've found this answer incredibly useful. I like being able to 'Hide' and 'Unhide' the launcher quickly without going to Settings->Appearance->Behaviour and then toggling the AutoHide ON/OFF button. I like to set up `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `P` to 'Put it away' and then `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `L` to show the Launcher and keep it there for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

For Unity 2D the dconf lines should be

```
/com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/hide-mode
```

There is also a third mode “Intellihide” whose value is 2.