# One command to get a running py script ID then kill it

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shortcuts

I once asked for a script to control unity launcher auto-hide behavior and the community here was kind and clever enough  to give me exactly what I needed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553539/how-can-i-auto-hide-the-launcher-via-a-script-when-i-maximize-the-browser).

Now I wonder if there is ONE command to grep this running py script ID then kill it as I want to add two keyboard shortcuts to switch this script on and off.

Comment: Your other question is quite interesting. Don't mind if I try to write another solution for it ?

Comment: yes sure. why not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `pkill`. If your script is named `myPythonScript.py`, you can run:

```
pkill -f myPythonScript.py
```

Note that that command will kill *all* running instances of `myPythonScript.py`. It will also kill any other process whose full commandline includes the string `myPythonScript.py` so, for example, it would kill your editor if you had launched it with something like `emacs myPythonScript.py`.

To be sure you kill only the running script, you can try matching the command more specifically:

```
pkill -f "/python.*myPythonScript.py"
```

That will only kill processes matching `/python`, 0 or more characters and the name of the script. Since the script will look like this in the list of processes:

```
terdon 20559  0.0  0.0  22768  7404 pts/4    S+   18:18   0:00 /bin/python /home/chapplec/scripts/myPythonScript.py
```

That should kill only running instances of the script.